# Replicate Excel's SUMIFS?

Tags: google-sheets

I wish to find the sum of Column A values where the respective Column B value is greater than or equal to some X and less than some Y.

I tried:

```
=SumIf(Sheet1!B:B, and(>=x, <y), Sheet1!A:A)
```

but it throws a parse error.

Answer (score 0):

I understand, SUMIF (Google Spreadsheet) allows a single criteria, and it is necessary to use other functions to achieve what is needed, e.g.

```
=SUM(FILTER(A:A; B:B >= X; B:B < Y))
```

Or

```
=SUM(QUERY(A:B; "SELECT A WHERE B >= X AND B < Y"))
```